# How to return an array response in Google App Engine endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to return a json output in GAE endpoints. How can I do it with messages.

```
{
    "items": [
        1: { ... }
        2: { ... }
        ...
    ]
}
```

e.g.

```
class Response(messages.Message):
    items = messages.StringField(1)
```

produces output

```
{
   "items": "message content"
}
```

How can I return an array for `items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a repeated field:

```
class Response(messages.Message):
    items = messages.StringField(1, repeated=True)
```

Comment: And how do we do this in Java?

Comment: Basically this will give a JSON object in response with key as "items" containing array of items. Any way we could directly return the JSON array of items without the wrapper key